# Why does my website appear in higher up in Google Search but then decrease?

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, meta-keywords, yoast

I am managing a WordPress website which offers tutorials on different concepts. Some of the keywords are coming between 3-4th page of Google search but some of them are above 10th pages.

Sometimes they appears 2-3th page or sometimes they disappears completely. I don't know what's going wrong.

I am using Yoast SEO for managing SEO part of my website. Can someone please provide me which is the best Yoast settings which works good.

One more thing I want to ask, I am keeping meta keywords and description same like "Java tutorial", "Java", "programming", etc... so both meta keywords and the description are the same. Can I do this, is it acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new page then you may expect slight changes in ranking and that's natural.

Meta title and description plugin only help you to frame your meta tag correctly, it doesn't have much-ranking influence.

The recommendation would continue to build good quality content which will be useful for the user.

Also, in your website link related tutorials from one another which may help users to stay longer on the page.

Try and market your content on social media and when other users will start linking your pages, you will see a significant ranking increase.